# How to select one particular child element when hovering parent using jquery?

Tags: jquery, hover, parent-child

I want to change the color of a child element when hovering a parent. The problem is that with the code below the child element (label color) changes for all columns while I only want it to change for that particular column. I guess I need to use 'this' in some way to make this work? So far have not been able to get this to work.

```
jQuery('.col-proposal').hover(function () {
jQuery('.col-proposal .label').css('color', 'green');
}, function () {
jQuery('.col-proposal .label').css('color', 'white');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use jquery? This can be done with CSS:

```
.col-proposal:hover .label {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Did not even know this could be done so simple with CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.col-propsal').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.label').first().css('color', 'green');
  // OR
  $(this).closest('.label').css('color', 'green');
  //OR 
  $(this).children('.label').css('color', 'green');
}, function(){
   ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to work on the currently hovered item by using `this`:

```
jQuery('.col-proposal').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.label').css('color', 'green');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.label').css('color', 'white');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you think good.

```
jQuery('.col-proposal').hover(function () {
  jQuery('.label', this).css('color', 'green');
}, function () {
  jQuery('.label', this).css('color', 'white');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.col-proposal').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.label').css('color', 'green');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.label').css('color', 'white');
});
```

By using this, you can select the currently active item